# c# wpf dispatcher.beginInvoke freeze

Tags: c#, wpf, freeze, dispatcher

im working on an application which communicates with server.

```
thread  = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClientStart));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);                
thread.Start();

private void ClientStart()
    {
        tcpClient = new TcpClient(ip,3000);
        stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        while (true) {                
            stream.Read(...);
            PrintMessage(...);
        .....
        }
}
private void PrintMessage(LogWin w, string msg)
{
  DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
  w.GetMessageBox().Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input,new Action(()=>w.GetMessageBox()
            .AppendText(String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt) + " : " + msg)));

}
```

later i need to print result to a messagebox. I know i have to use Dispatcher, because im working in another thread, but my application freezes even if i use beginInvoke method.

**Edit based on Sheridan's answer**:

now im getting:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
thread = new Thread(() => ClientStart(dispatcher));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();

private void ClientStart(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    { 
....
```

and changed print method:

```
 dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
       w.GetMessageBox()
            .AppendText(String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt) + " : " + msg)));
```

**solved** by using `Application.Current.Dispatcher`

Comment: I believe printing on MessageBox doesnt require to Invoke UI

Comment: The dispatcher thread is just that - a single thread. It can only process things in sequence. If you call Dispatcher.Invoke then your delegate will be added to the queue and processed according to the priority. What this means is that while your delegate is being processed the Dispatcher will not be able to pump messages, so your UI will lock up.

Comment: How long does it take stream.Read to complete? You have a tight loop with the while(true) statement, so you may not be yielding enough resources to allow the message pump to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always be wary of `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` as that will will return an object for dispatching on the CURRENT thread - which may not be the UI.  You want (and generally almost always want) the UI thread dispatcher.

You can get that through `Application.Current.Dispatcher` Which always returns the UI thread dispatcher.

Its frustating that these calls looks so similar...

[If you are in the main window you can just call `Dispatcher` but that probably not the case for you]

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> In WPF, only the thread that created a `DispatcherObject` may access that object

Therefore, if you first called the `Dispatcher` from your background thread, then it can only run on that background thread. Instead of that, ensure that you 'initialise' your `Dispatcher` object on the UI thread:

```
Dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

From the [`Dispatcher` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> If you attempt to get the `CurrentDispatcher` for the current thread and a `Dispatcher` is not associated with the thread, a `Dispatcher` will be created.

Then passing a reference to that UI thread `Dispatcher` to your background thread will enable you to access the UI thread again from the background thread.